# Wrong time with localtime()

Tags: c++, c

Running `date`on my server results in the correct time. But using `localtime()` in C(++) I'm getting the wrong time.

Running `date`: `Fr 30. Nov 12:15:36 CET 2012`

Using `localtime()`: `Fr 30 Nov 2012 11:15:36 CET`

What's wrong here?

OS: Debian 5.0.10

Some code:

```
struct tm* today;
today = localtime(...);
strftime(timeBuffer,50,myConnection.getMetaData().getDateFormat().c_str(),today);
```

Comment: Not being an expert, it seems to me an issue with summer/winter time. Date probably takes it into account and adds a 1 or 2 hours depending on that.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what `myConnection.getMetaData().getDateFormat().c_str()` is. Did you hardcode CET or is that `%z`? Something's not right here. (And yes I know it's an old post!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : some serious grave digging here heh. But a good thing too, because the answers are indeed not appropriate. Ref. my comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **disclaimer** : This answer was written before any mention of `strftime` was added, and was a gut reaction to the 1 hour difference in the timestamps. Looking back at it now, that 1 hour difference couldn't have been due to DST (because the dates are not in summer), but is likely showing a UTC timestamp (1 hour difference between UTC and CET).
>
> Unfortunately, the answer was accepted, and so I can't delete it. Even more unfortunate, is that the question as it stands is not answerable without additional information.
>
> Leaving the original answer here for full transparency, but know that it does not address the question as asked :

The `struct tm` returned by `localtime` has a `tm_isdst` field that indicates whether daylight saving time (DST) is in effect. You need to take that field into account when formatting the time.

Try using `asctime` to format the time eg. :

```
puts(asctime(today));
```

Comment: Actually `asctime()` also takes into account the `tm_isdst` so the hour still be "wrong" in terms of what OP has expected.

Comment: to downvoters : this answer was written before any mention of `strftime` was added, and was a gut reaction to the 1 hour difference in the timestamps. Looking back at it now, that 1 hour difference couldn't have been due to DST (because the dates are not in summer), but is likely showing a UTC timestamp (1 hour difference between UTC and CET). I'd guess either some trickery was going on with timezone settings on the op's platform, or there were inaccuracies in the question. In any case, I'll delete this answer in a short while, because as it stands, it can only serve to confuse readers.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem while writing a date adjustment routine. Adding 86400 seconds (= 1 day) to any given datetime value *should* result in incrementing the datetime value by one day.  However in testing, the output value invariably added exactly one hour to the expected output. For instance, '2019-03-20 **00**:00:00' incremented by 86400 seconds resulted in '2019-03-21 **01**:00:00'. The reverse also occurred: '2019-03-21 **00**:00:00' *decremented* by -86400 resulted in '2019-03-20 **01**:00:00'.

<s>The solution (inexplicably) was to subtract 3600 seconds (one hour) from the final interval before applying it to the input datetime.</s>

The solution (*thanks to helpful comments from @Lightness-Races-in-Orbit*) was to set `tm_isdst` to -1 before calling `mktime()`. This tells `mktime()` that the DST status for the input datetime value is unknown, and that `mktime()` should use the system timezone databases to determine the correct timezone for the input datetime value.

The function (*as corrected below*) allows for any integer adjustment of days and now produces consistently correct results:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>        

/*******************************************************************************
 *  \fn             adjust_date()
 *******************************************************************************/

int adjust_date(
                        char    *original_date,
                        char    *adjusted_date,
                        char    *pattern_in,
                        char    *pattern_out,
                        int      adjustment,
                        size_t   out_size)
{
/*
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         // seconds          0-59
    int tm_min;         // minutes          0-59
    int tm_hour;        // hours            0-23
    int tm_mday;        // day of the month 1-31
    int tm_mon;         // month            0-11
    int tm_year;        // year       minus 1900
    int tm_wday;        // day of the week  0-6
    int tm_yday;        // day in the year  0-365
    int tm_isdst;       // daylight saving time 
};
*/
    struct tm day;

    time_t one_day = 86400;
//  time_t interval = (one_day * adjustment) - 3600;
    time_t interval = (one_day * adjustment);

    strptime(original_date, pattern_in, &day);

    day.tm_isdst = -1;
    time_t t1 = mktime(&day);

    if (t1 == -1) {
        printf("The mktime() function failed");
        return -1;
    }

    time_t t2 = t1 + interval;

    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&t2);

    if (ptm == NULL) {
        printf("The localtime() function failed");
        return -1;
    }

    strftime(adjusted_date, out_size, pattern_out, ptm);

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 *  \fn             main()
 *******************************************************************************/
int main()
{
    char    in_date[64]     = "20190321000000" ,
            out_date[64],
            pattern_in[64]  = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S",
            pattern_out[64] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

    int     day_diff = -1,
            ret = 0;

    size_t  out_size = 64;

    memset(out_date, 0, sizeof(out_date));

    ret = adjust_date(in_date, out_date, pattern_in, pattern_out, day_diff, out_size); 

    if (ret == 0)
    {
        printf("Adjusted date: '%s'\n", out_date);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Hopefully, this will be of some help to somebody. Your constructive comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Adding 86400 seconds (= 1 day) to any given datetime value should result in incrementing the datetime value by one day"_ Nooooooo. Not every day has 86400 seconds. First, depending on the timebase, there are leap seconds (though if you're using UNIX timestamps then it's okay because UNIX ignores leap seconds, just slewing the clock over them instead -.-). Second, there are DST changes (_if_ you are being timezone-aware). Just removing an hour is a hack that will almost certainly break for you at some point. Instead, _don't do this_ for incrementing datestamps!

Comment: (It's likely that one part of your logic considers DST and the other does not - have you tried timestamps in December?)

Comment: Furthermore, though potentially an interesting question in its own right, this answer does not really seem to address the question posed, sorry

Comment: Eureka, @Lightness-Races-in-Orbit, you are a genius!

The _true_ solution was to set `tm_isdst` to -1 before calling `mktime()`. This tells `mktime()` that the DST status for the input datetime value is unknown, and that `mktime()` should use the system timezone databases to determine the correct timezone for the input datetime value.

The function (_as corrected above_) allows for any integer adjustment of days and now produces consistently correct results.

Hopefully, this may shed some light on the original poster's question, as `mktime()` and `localtime()` are related.

Comment: I have my moments :P

Comment: Personally I'd stick with UTC for this throughout `adjust_date`. So 0 not -1, and gmtime not localtime

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ? :

```
 time_t rawtime;
 struct tm * today;

 time ( &rawtime );
 today= localtime ( &rawtime );
 puts(asctime (today));
```

Answer (score 0):

handling date time is very error prone and usually badly tested. i always recommend using boost::date_time http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time.html

here are nice examples http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/datetime.html